# Al ordenar los simbolos aritmeticos no se imprime el simbolo "-"

Tags: java

hola me pidieron que cuando se ingresen los simbolos aritmeticos despues se imprimieran ordenados por prioridad, actualice el codigo por un error que yo no te pero al imprimir las variables me salen null

```
package sig_ar_ord;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sig_ar_ord {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String[] s_a=new String[8];
String[] sa=new String[8];
String[] s_a_o={"[","]","(",")","*","/","%","+","-"};
 int x=0;
String aux;
     //0[ 1] 2( 3)
     //4* 5/ 6%
     //7+ 8-
for (int i = 0; i <4; i++) {
    System.out.println("Escribe el signo aritmetico ");
    s_a[i]=sc.next();

}

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <8; j++) {
        if (s_a[i].equals(s_a_o[j])) {
            sa[j]=s_a[i];
        }
    }

}
System.out.println("Los simbolos en orden son:");
for (int i = 0; i <8; i++) {
   if(sa[i]!=null) {
       System.out.println(sa[i]);
   }

}



}

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias contarnos cual es la salida que recibis y la salida esperada? y como primer paso te diria que nombres mejor a tus variables. que es s_a o s_a_o????

Comment: La salida que recibo son solamente null pero esperaría que diera como salida  el orden de los símbolos ingresados por el teclado en orden de prioridad

Comment: y podrias hacer un [edit] en tu pregunta, y explicar la logica de tu funcion de comparacion? porque no entiendo que quisiste hacer, y obviamente esto es un ejercicio, y me gustaria ayudarte mas que resolverlo

Comment: estas imprimiendo sa. que siempre esta vacio. nunca lo completas con nada

Comment: si lo note muchas gracias por tu solidaridad ante mi problema, logre que funcionara a medias dado a que el programa al iprimir no me imprime el simbolo de "-"

Comment: Hagan el favor de utilizar variables inteligibles. Poner nombres de variables es gratuito y poner las variables algo más descriptivas ayuda en el futuro a gestionar estas aplicaciones (ya no hablo de si otros programadores toman el mismo SW y lo continuan). Cojan costumbre desde sus inicios, por el bien comunitario :)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error en el orden estas asignando a una referencia equivocada

Cambia

s_a[j]=sa[x];

Por

sa[x]=s_a[j];